# Why does numpy have this quirk when indexing with slices vs. lists?

Tags: python, numpy

One would think that indexing with slices and equivalent lists is equivalent in the result, and it mostly is:

```
>>> b = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
>>> b[0:2,0:2] # slice & slice
array([[0, 1],
    [3, 4]])
>>> b[0:2,[0,1]] # slice & list
array([[0, 1],
    [3, 4]])
>>> b[[0,1],0:2] # list & slice
array([[0, 1],
    [3, 4]])
```

However:

```
>>> b[[0,1],[0,1]] # list & list
array([0, 4])
```

Okay, there is a work-around:

```
>>> b[[0,1],:][:,[0,1]]
array([[0, 1],
    [3, 4]])
```

But why is this necessary?

(Note: I originally refered to slices as "ranges".)

Comment: When you index with two lists, Numpy just returns an array of all numbers that are accessed by the index pairs `(i,j)`. Why would you expect that example to return a matrix in the first place? What you tell Numpy is, "give me all numbers that correspond to these indices".

Comment: Terminology note, that is not a "range" that is a "slice"

Comment: How else are you going to select the diagonal?

Comment: @hpaulj Why, with `b.diagonal()`. This double advanced indexing seems more suited for accessing arbitrary elements, but I can't quite figure out its rules. (Especially considering how `b[[0,1],:]==b`.)

Comment: I meant 'diagonal' in a general sense.  The diagonal of `b[[0,1],:][:,[0,1]]` is [0,4], which is what you get with the `b[[0,1], [0,1]]`.  With lists or arrays of the same 1d size, indexing does select arbitrary points.  To approach the problem from different direction, do `np.nonzero` on an array with 0s and nonzeros.  The resulting tuple of arrays can be used directly to index the nonzero elements.  But as my answer shows arrays can also index blocks - if they `broadcast` appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One would think that indexing with ranges and equivalent lists is equivalent in the result

One would be wrong. When you say "ranges" you actually mean "slices". In any case, indexing with a slice is considered ["basic indexing"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), and indexing with a list (or array) is ["advanced indexing"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

The rules to how these two mix together and the shape of the resulting array are pretty arcane. However, your examples are the simplest case, a single advanced index and a basic index (the slice), from [the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing):

> In the simplest case, there is only a single advanced index. A single
> advanced index can for example replace a slice and the result array
> will be the same, however, it is a copy and may have a different
> memory layout. A slice is preferable when it is possible.

So, you'll notice, advanced indexing will always create a copy, if you only use basic indexing, you get a *view*. This is an important distinction (1).

But that explains why the slicing seem equivalent in *that specific case*. However, in the case of:

```
>>> b = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
>>> b[[0,1],[0,1]]
array([0, 4])
```

This is just [purely integer array advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing)

> When the index consists of as many integer arrays as the array being
> indexed has dimensions, the indexing is straight forward, but
> different from slicing.
>
> Advanced indexes always are broadcast and iterated as *one*
> `result[i_1, ..., i_M] == x[ind_1[i_1, ..., i_M], ind_2[i_1, ..., i_M], ..., ind_N[i_1, ..., i_M]]`

##### (1) The difference between views and copies, basic vs advanced indxeing

```
>>> b = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
>>> view = b[0:2,0:2]
>>> copy = b[0:2,[0,1]]
>>> view
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
>>> copy
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
>>> view[0,0] = 1337
>>> b
array([[1337,    1,    2],
       [   3,    4,    5]])
>>> view
array([[1337,    1],
       [   3,    4]])
>>> copy
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addenda to Juanpa's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70212077/901925
you can use two arrays to get the block - but they have to `broadcast` against each other.

```
In [348]: b = np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
In [349]: b[[[0],[1]], [0,1]]
Out[349]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

`np.ix_` is a convenience function for creating this kind of indexing set:

```
In [350]: np.ix_([0,1],[0,1])
Out[350]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 1]]))
In [351]: b[np.ix_([0,1],[0,1])]
Out[351]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

The first index array is (n,1) shape, the second (1,m); together they define a (n,m) space.

You specified a (n,) and (n,) pair, which `broadcast` to (n,).  Think of this as the 'diagonal' of [351].

In some languages like MATLAB pairs of indexing arrays like this do specify the block.  But to get the diagonal, you have use an extra step, something like `sub2ind` to convert the pairs to a 1d indexing array.  In `numpy` the block index requires the extra `ix_` like step, but logically it's all explainable by `broadcasting`.